# Troubleshoot `IF` function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking for a simple formula to show:

- If the cell F11 shows 1, then G11 will display 33%
- If F11 shows 2, then G11 will display 66%
- If it show 3, then G11 will display 100%

I've tried the below `IF` formula but it says I have too many arguments, can anyone help?

`=IF(AND(F11=0),"0%",OR(F11=1),"33%",OR(F11=2),"66%"OR(F11=3),"100%"))`

Comment: Why not `=rounddown(100*F11/3;0)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Cell `G11` use:

```
=IF(F11=1,33%,IF(F11=2,66%,IF(F11=3,100%,"IF ELSE GOES HERE")))
```

Format `G11` as percentage, or it may display as `0.33` etc.

Replace `"IF ELSE GOES HERE"` for what you want in the instance where `F11` is neither 1,2 or 3, To leave blank you could simply use `""`

Comment: How do you enter this formula from,say, G12, but to work on G11?

Comment: @Nick Uh, you can't? You can't make it so one cell changes another cell.

Answer (score 11):

*You can try this formula also has a different appraoch:*

```
=IF(OR(F11=1,F11=2,F11=3),CHOOSE(F11,0.33,0.66,1),0)
```

**How this works:**

- Excel checks `F11` & if it has either `1`, or `2` or `3` then executes the
  `CHOOSE` function accordingly and returns `0.33 for (33%)`, `0.66 for (66%)` 
  or `1 for (100%)`.
- `F11` always returns `0` if it has value other than `1` or `2` or `3`, even 
  in case of Text & Date also it returns `0`.

Comment: I like the CHOOSE option, works very well when the amount of IFs gets larger, much easier to write than multiple nested IF statements.

Comment: Thanks @PeterH,, each appreciation encourage to do better , have nice day :-)

Comment: Congrats.  This answers was chosen as an [audit test](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/778306) in the LQP review queue (high-scoring posts used for that).

Comment: Thanks @fixer1234,, you always encouraged me to improve. Have Nice Weekend ☺

Answer (score 8):

Why not just use the following formula in F11?

```
=G11/3
```

(and format F11 as Percent with 0 decimal places)

Answer (score 4):

[`IF`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) need to be used like this:

> IF(Something is True, then do something, otherwise do something else)

So your formula will be:

`=IF(F11=0,0,IF(F11=1,0.33,IF(F11=2,0.66,IF(F11=3,1))))`

or splited to make it more clear:

```
=IF(F11=0,
    0,
    IF(F11=1,
       0.33,
       IF(F11=2,
          0.66,
          IF(F11=3
             ,1
           )
       )
    )
 )
```